# Javascript / Parse: Follow wont return 'to' value

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to get all of the users that are following the current user. From some reason Parse returns the username as undefined in the 'to' field but I am able to retrieve the user name from the 'from' field like so:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Follow");
    query.equalTo("to", Parse.User.current());
    query.find({
        success: function(users){
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                console.log(users[i].get('from').get('username')) // returns current username
                console.log(users[i].get('to').get('username')) / returns undefined
            }
        }
    });
```

But those values do exist and there is a username. I am able to get the value using the fetch method but I am curious as to why this approach doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you can first try log `users[i].get('to')` to see what structure is it.

Comment: Thats the thing, it does return the user:
 't {_objCount: 11, className: "_User", id: "imnmEPzkS2"}'  but then if I take it one step further and say users[i].get('to').attributes it returns undefined

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Doc](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-relationships), you're not getting the actual object, but the ref to that object:

> Internally, the Parse framework will store the referred-to object in just one place, to maintain consistency. ......

And

> By default, *when fetching an object, related Parse.Objects are not
>   fetched*. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have
>   been fetched like so:

```
// Here, post is something similar to your `users[i].get('to')`
var post = fetchedComment.get("parent"); 

// So you need to fetch it again to get its real object.
post.fetch({
    success: function(post) {
        var title = post.get("title");   
    } 
});
```

So what you get from `users[i].get('to')` is a reference to that user object. You can either fetch it again.